# Python - How to print Sqlite table

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Here I have some simple python code to query a sqlite3 database.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

conn = lite.connect('db/posts.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

def get_posts():
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Posts")
    print(cur.fetchall())

get_posts()
```

I have already created the table `Posts`. When I run this I get no errors, and it just prints out `[]`. I know that the table Posts isn't empty, I created it in a REPL. Why is this not working?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a context manager, so you don´t have to commit!

```
def get_posts():
    with conn:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Posts")
        print(cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: You wouldn't have to commit anyway because the statement being executed does not modify the database

Answer (score 9):

Turns out I just forgot to use `conn.commit()`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Actually, why would you need to add a `commit` if the data is not modified? Is that a `sqlite` thing?

Comment: I had a totally unrelated problem where my stuff wasn't writing to the database so I can here to see how to print it and the answer was that I wasn't committing so this saved me plenty of time, thank you!