# How to print data from SQLite3 in table format in python VS CODE

Tags: python, sqlite

How can I print data in table format with headers? Like in the photo I posted here[image]

Is it even possible? My code here:

```
    conn = sql.connect("register.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM datas ORDER BY lastname")
    record = cur.fetchall()
    for item in record:
        print(item[0],"  ",item[1],"  ",item[2],"  ",item[3],"  ",item[4])
    print("Wpisz nr id: ")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to print Sqlite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015980/python-how-to-print-sqlite-table), have you tried to `print(record)` ?

Comment: No this isn't this answer I can print out data from SQLite3 but not in format table that's every column and line is even with headers

Comment: The question is how to print in pretty format like in the photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [the sqlite row_factory *Row*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) to get access to the column names (to be used as titles) using the keys method. Then use something like the string method [ljust](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ljust#str.ljust) in the print statment, supplying the desired `width`s to get the formatting you desire.